# How to set DateTime picker minimum date and type

Tags: c#, maui

How do i set the minimum value of a date picker in xaml to be today's date plus two days (in other words the mininmum value should be two days from now) and how do i set its type to be a DateTime ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `MinimumDate` and `MaximumDate` properties

```
myDatePicker.MinimumDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
```